# How to add field or button outside a tree view on openerp?

Tags: button, treeview, field, openerp-7

How can I add a field/button outside a tree view on openerp? I've tried a lot to imitate how they add on journal items but I always failed because the default module for accounting involves a java-script. I want a simple field only and add an on_change behaviour on it.

Answer (score 0):

@Anirudh Lou

You can add button two way basically :

1. You can either add button on any of the view  (tree, form, kanba...) this  button are designed to trigger some business logic. Their are some exception where you can see button on form view but those are special implementation (like reconciliation, timehsheet...) which is done using second way.
2. Or you can use Javascript add add button anywhere interface but those button usually for more generic functionality. If you want to add button like **Create**, **Edit** you need too add using Javascript and Templates by creating Web module. [**Here's the tutorial**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html) to create the web extension modules.

Yes you can do hacking some piece of code but I wouldn't recommend that cause that open gate to infinite problem that you dont wanna run into and also its security risk that thing can be tapped from their. But either way you need to hit the Javascript to add the button on the screen.

Bests